# Breakpoint in visual studio not load at moment debug

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a solution with 3 projects, one of them being Ex.utils and Ex.Api. Where the .dll of the utils project is referenced in Ex.Api in 'References'. Both compiled in the same .NET version.

When you run the debug, the breakpoint, after countless searches, remains as if unavailable.

[image]

Comment: You should use project reference, not the dll reference.

Comment: I already tested referenced the project. The same error still occurs.

Comment: Your question states you referenced the .DLL of the "utils project".  A project reference is different from a DLL reference.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to clean the Solution
2. Try to Build and Rebuild the solution
3. Check if your in debug and not release
4. If Still not work try to delete the .dll in the debug/bin folder
5. If Not work try to restart your PC

thanks